# Will system partitions be restored after clean install of Windows 10 and wiping the drive of all partitions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

I'm thinking about wiping all of the partitions from a 2TB RAID 0 and doing a clean install.

Some of the partitions, upon reading about it, contain necessary drivers for the OS. I'm curious if deleting all partitions, then doing a clean install of the OS, will restore these partitions. Or if these partitions are related to BIOS and the hardware to even load a bootable USB.

Trying to avoid bricking my laptop, but I'm trying to merge the `E:\` with the `C:\`, but can't due to these system values being between them. Thus, thinking about wiping it clean to hopefully resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Reinstalling will create those 4 partitions again, so that is not the solution. You can however just resize and move partitions. Windows does not offer this functionality well, but AIOMEI Partition manager has a free version that works really well. Make Partition E really small, move the other partitions, then increase the size of C, move data over, and then remove E and move the other partitions.

Comment: I tried doing that with NIUBI with no luck. Maybe AIOMEI will work better. https://superuser.com/questions/1388302/merge-two-partitions-separated-by-important-system-volumes-non-adjacent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the partitions you were reading about are manufacturer recovery partitions.  These are partitions created by your computers manufacturer that may contain software and/or drivers to restore the computer to state it was shipped with.  These partitions are not necessary for the computer to function.  However, removing them will break that recovery functionality.  Typically, they can be restored via software downloaded from the manufacturer.

Based on your image, you do not have a manufacturer recovery partition.  You are safe to delete all the partitions on your drive and create new partitions on the drive.

Comment: OK, sounds good! Yeah the recovery partition was the E:\ but it became corrupted. The system would no longer try to do a clean install from it if you went into recovery (F9, I think). So had to make a separate bootable USB. 12GB was just sitting there unused to formatted it when I ran this issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1388302/merge-two-partitions-separated-by-important-system-volumes-non-adjacent